# NPM update package and peer dependency together to avoid conflicts

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to do something that seems very logical to me but for some reason doesn't work.

Right now I have the following dependencies:

```
...
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0"
...
```

I'm trying to update the latter, but it requires `eslint@">=7.5.0` as a peer dependency.
In order to update both of them, I try `npm install @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5 eslint@7`, but get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: sci-annot@0.1.6
npm ERR! Found: @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.19
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">=7.5.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

The error makes no sense to me. It's complaining that `eslint@7.32.0` conflicts with `eslint">=7.5.0"`.

Comment: Says `Found: @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.19` so what does `npm ls @vue/cli-plugin-eslint` say?

Comment: @morganney Just `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.19`